# How to preserve line breaks when sending JSON using cURL?

Tags: bash, curl

The following almost works, but line breaks in `message` property are not preserved.

```sh
output="$(ls -la /home/john | gpg --armor --encrypt --recipient john@example.net)"
curl \
  --request POST \
  --url https://api.example.net/sendmail \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data @- << EOF
{
  "subject": "Test",
  "message": "$output"
}
EOF
```

Thanks for helping out!

Comment: JSON can't contain literal line breaks in strings, they have to be converted to `\n`.

Comment: Use the `jq` utility to create JSON rather than doing it with string substitution.

Comment: Thanks for helping out… is there a way to do this without having to install a package?

Comment: @Barmar Using [jo](https://github.com/jpmens/jo) works perfectly (thanks for the hint in this direction), but can’t one handle this natively using Bash?

Comment: @sunknudsen bash doesn't have any built-in JSON capability; you either need an external program or to build it yourself from basic string manipulations (which is very complex to do right).

Comment: `--request POST` should be dropped from this command line, `--data` implies POST

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace all the newlines with `\n` in the JSON string:

```
message=${message//$'\n'/\\n}
```

However, I recommend using a utility like `jq` rather than ad hoc code like this. You also need to escape double quotes and backslashes in the string, and convert non-ASCII characters to `\u####` escape sequences.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! Will keep utilities in mind for more complex use cases.